# How to filter IP and PORT to two variables

Tags: python

am trying to get proxies in two variables from module called proxyscrape

How it looks:

```
import proxyscrape

collector = proxyscrape.create_collector('default', 'socks5')
proxy = collector.get_proxy()

print(proxy)
```

Output:

```
Proxy(host='112.13.170.142', port='80', code=None, country=None, anonymous=None, type='socks5', source='proxy-daily-socks5')
```

What i need, is to parse, so i can use it in requests

```
import proxyscrape

collector = proxyscrape.create_collector('default', 'socks5')
proxy = collector.get_proxy()

ip = ip
port = port
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Most likely, you can simply do `proxy.host` and `proxy.port`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this.

```
 ip = proxy.host
 port = proxy.port
```

If those attributes exist on the `proxy` object, then you should be able to set a variable to them.

Comment: its not, i need to use regex

Comment: You can't parse an object with regex. I would recommend reading over their docs https://pypi.org/project/proxyscrape/)